# How to emulate a 64 bit pointer in a 32 bit application

Tags: c#, windows, pointers, x86-64

I have a 32 bit usermode application written in C# and I need to emulate the behavior of a 64 bit pointer. I know that I can compile for 64 bit, but I am using the directx9 dlls which would become incompatible once I change the target architecture.

My problem is that the IntPtr class type is too small at 4 bytes large and causes issues when communicating with the kernel mode driver which is 64 bit. I need a 64 bit pointer to match the structs on the driver.

My question is if there is any way to create a 64 bit pointer on a c# application? Are there any wrapper classes that can do this for me?

```cs
ideally:

IntPtr32 pnt32; //would 4 bytes large
IntPtr64 pnt64; //and this would be 8 bytes large
```

Comment: Use a `long` to force 64 bit.

Comment: What do you want to do with this pointer? You can’t use a 64-bit address to access memory from a 32-bit application.

Answer (score 0):

After trying what Raymond suggested, using a long to force a 64 bit variable, I can confirm that while hacky it does work.

A little background of what this pointer needs to do. The driver and the usermode application both have a struct used to send requests to each other. The struct has a void* that is written to by the driver and sent by the usermode application. It acts as a buffer for the user to read information from after the request is finished.

```cs
//NOTE: alot of stuff ommitted for simplicity

T buffer = default;
IntPtr pBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(buffer));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(buffer, pBuffer, false);

//construct struct for the read request
KERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadRequest = new KERNEL_READ_REQUEST();
ReadRequest.pBuff = pBuffer.ToInt64(); //long type variable in struct

if(DeviceIoControl(&ReadRequest)){ 
    buffer = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pBuffer, typeof(T));

    //return buffer and free memory
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBuffer); //free the memory

    return buffer;
}
```

I won't mark this as an answer because it doesn't really feel right using a long to store a 64 bit address, but i'll leave what worked for me here.

Comment: The keyword `long` is an alias for `System.Int64`.  Feel free to use the type name instead of the alias.